# Package-level instance method vs public instance method? java

Tags: java, instance, getter

So lets say I have a class called Person:

```
public class Person {

    private final String name;
    private final int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }

}
```

For the getName() and getAge() methods, should I use the public modifier, or just keep them as package-level instance methods? What if I had a void method for the class? Would I keep that as a package-level instance method, or should I set it to be public?

Comment: An access modifier does not affect if a method is an _instance_ method or not.

Comment: An instance method is one that doesn't have the `static` modifier. Methods with a visibility modifier have default or "package" visibility. In general, use public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The visibility of your methods depends *entirely* on your program design and your desired public API. Because of this, the return type and whether the method is instance/static has no effect on whether your method should be public or not. There's no straightforward answer because of that.

> For the `getName()` and `getAge()` methods, should I use the `public` modifier, or just keep them as package-level instance methods?

Now, I'm *guessing* as to how you want your `Person` class to work, but it would not be unreasonable to assume that this is a class that anyone can use, and you want anyone to be able to see a `Person`'s age and name. Thus, it probably makes sense to use `public`.

> What if I had a void method for the class? Would I keep that as a package-level instance method, or should I set it to be public?

This depends *entirely* on what that method is. The return type is irrelevant

---

I think a good rule of thumb is to expose *behaviors*, not *implementations*. You want your public API to describe the behaviors that your object is capable of. You *don't* want to expose *how* those behaviors are implemented, because that means that someone might rely on that implementation being there, thus limiting your ability to change your implementation later. For small projects, this isn't a big deal, but for larger projects this becomes more important.

Here are some choice quotes from *Effective Java, 2nd edition* by Joshua Bloch, Item 13:

> The single most important factor that distinguishes a well-designed module from a poorly designed one is the degree to which the module hides its internal data and other implementation details from other modules. A well-designed module hides all of its implementation details, cleanly separating its API from its implementation. Modules then communicate only through their APIs and are oblivious to each others’ inner workings.
>
> The rule of thumb is simple: **make each class or member as inaccessible as possible**. In other words, use the lowest possible access level consistent with the proper functioning of the software that you are writing.
>
> To summarize, you should always reduce accessibility as much as possible. After carefully designing a minimal public API, you should prevent any stray classes, interfaces, or members from becoming a part of the API.

Bloch goes more into detail, but those are some of the main points. I highly recommend giving that book a read; there's a lot more good advice in there that you might find helpful.